# Javascript cordova_plugin.js returning error 500

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap-build, phonegap, pythonanywhere

Notes:
Using PhoneGap Desktop on Windows 10 Pro v0.4.5. When I try to run the application, the jQuery Ajax request is not being received by the PythonAnywhere server. Is this because of the error caused by cordova_plugins.js not loading correctly? What can be done to load it correctly and resolve the errors?

Full error message:

```
GET http://192.168.56.1:3000/cordova_plugins.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)
exports.injectScript @ cordova.js:1528
injectIfNecessary @ cordova.js:1536
exports.load @ cordova.js:1616
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1129
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1128
build @ cordova.js:53
require @ cordova.js:68
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1861
(anonymous) @ cordova.js:1863
```

JavaScript / HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Mobile Application</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

    <style>
    body{
        background: url(images/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .headerText{
        color: white;
    }
    #searchForHouses{
        background: transparent;
        /*border: 1px solid gray;*/
        color: white;
    }
    .feature{
        width: 88%;
        height: 70%;
        /*margin: 10%;*/
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getDataForSearch(){
            alert("Button clicked")
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                headers:{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}, 
                url: "[username].pythonanywhere.com/getData", 
                data: {
                    requesttype: "getSearchData", 
                }, 
                success: function(results){
                    alert(results)
                },
                error: function(error){
                    alert("Error: "+error)
                }
            })
        }

        function functionOne(){
            // alert("Href Clicked")
        }
    </script>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1 class='headerText'>RealEstate.com.au</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <a href="#pagetwo" onclick="functionOne()"><button onclick="getDataForSearch()" id='searchForHouses'>Search for Houses</button></a>

            <div class='feature'>
                f
            </div>
        </div>

<!--          <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div> -->
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="pagetwo" data-theme="b">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1 class='headerText'>RealEstate.com.au</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

            <a href="#pageone">Go to Page One</a>
        </div>

<!--        <div data-role="footer">
            <h1>Footer Text</h1>
        </div> -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In you error messages it seems like you are trying to load cordova_plugins.js from 192.168.56.1:3000. that sounds wrong

Answer (score 0):

Look in your error and server logs in your PythonAnywhere web app to see what the error is.

Comment: Thanks! I checked it last night and didn't see any errors. The log mustn't have updated or something. Anyway, here is the error: https://pastebin.com/F51K7HPj

Comment: It looks like you must be setting `application` to a list in your WSGI file.